# Changing an orientation of a reverse sequence in the fasta file doesnt work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pysam

I am trying to get the reverse sequences orientated correctly in a file. This is the code:

```
import os
import sys import pysam
from Bio import SeqIO, Seq, SeqRecord

def main(in_file):
    out_file = "%s.fa" % os.path.splitext(in_file)[0]
    with open(out_file, "w") as out_handle:
        # Write records from the BAM file one at a time to the output file.
        # Works lazily as BAM sequences are read so will handle large files.
        SeqIO.write(bam_to_rec(in_file), out_handle, "fasta")

def bam_to_rec(in_file):
    """Generator to convert BAM files into Biopython SeqRecords.
    """
bam_file = pysam.Samfile(in_file, "rb")
for read in bam_file:
    seq = Seq.Seq(read.seq)
    if read.is_reverse:
        seq = seq.reverse_complement()
    rec = SeqRecord.SeqRecord(seq, read.qname, "", "")
    yield rec

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])`
```

When I print out the reverse sequences, the code works. But when in the file it is printed out as a reverse sequence. Can anyone help me to find out what is going wrong?
Here is the link to my infile:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/68ui8l7nh5fxatm/AABUr82l01qT1nL8I_XgJaeTa?dl=0

Comment: shouldn't your rec = SeqRecord and your yield be inside the for loop?

Comment: That only prints out a single sequence.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 1):

Note the ugly counter is just to print 10000 sequences, not more.

comparing one without ever reversing with one that reverses if needed
Here's the output on a couple of seqs, feel free to test it, I think your issue is that yield returns an iterator but you are not iterating it, unless I am missunderstanding what you are doing:

Original:

> SOLEXA-1GA-2:2:93:1281:961#0
>   GGGTTAGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAG

Becomes:

> SOLEXA-1GA-2:2:93:1281:961#0
>   CTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCTAACCC

And if not reverse:

Original:

> SOLEXA-1GA-2:2:12:96:1547#0
>   ACACACAAACACACACACACACACACACACACCCCC

Becomes:

> SOLEXA-1GA-2:2:12:96:1547#0
>   ACACACAAACACACACACACACACACACACACCCCC
>   Here's my code:

```
import os
import sys 
import pysam
from Bio import SeqIO, Seq, SeqRecord

def main(in_file):
    out_file = "%s.fa" % os.path.splitext(in_file)[0]
    with open('test_non_reverse.txt', 'w') as non_reverse:
        with open(out_file, "w") as out_handle:
            # Write records from the BAM file one at a time to the output file.
            # Works lazily as BAM sequences are read so will handle large files.
            i = 0
            for s in bam_to_rec(in_file):
                if i == 10000:
                   break
                i +=1 
                SeqIO.write(s, out_handle, "fasta")
            i = 0
            for s in convert_to_seq(in_file):
                if i == 10000:
                   break
                i +=1

                SeqIO.write(s, non_reverse, 'fasta')

def convert_to_seq(in_file):
    bam_file = pysam.Samfile(in_file, "rb")
    for read in bam_file:
        seq = Seq.Seq(read.seq)
        rec = SeqRecord.SeqRecord(seq, read.qname, "", "")
        yield rec


def bam_to_rec(in_file):
    """Generator to convert BAM files into Biopython SeqRecords.
    """
    bam_file = pysam.Samfile(in_file, "rb")
    for read in bam_file:
        seq = Seq.Seq(read.seq)
        if read.is_reverse:
            seq = seq.reverse_complement()
        rec = SeqRecord.SeqRecord(seq, read.qname, "", "")
        yield rec

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. It actually prints the right sequences in the .txt file. Some of the sequences are duplicated also.

Comment: Does that mean you only want the original sequences? (if so change your call to bam_to_rec for a call to  convert_to_seq).Are they duplicated in the bam file?

Comment: Interestingly, I want the reversed sequenced but these are in the .txt file. Sometimes there are 2 in the original bam file (the forward and the reverse read). The ID looks like this: M03972:51:000000000-BJVL8:1:2108:21571:6518/2      When printed out they only look like this: M03972:51:000000000-BJVL8:1:2108:21571:6518 so the number the slash disappear. That then makes problems for the further analysis as it sees it as a duplicated sequences. Is there a way to filter them  out?